# Getting a Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop although I already have a key prop in the Grid component from Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code below.

Home.js

```
import { CircularProgress, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Posts from "../../components/Posts/Posts";
import { fetchPosts } from '../../redux';

function Home() {

    const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPosts());
    }, [dispatch]);

    if ((posts && posts.posts.length <= 0) || posts.loading) {
        return <CircularProgress />
    }

    if (posts.posts.posts.length <= 0) {
        return <h3>No posts currently.</h3>
    }

    // handle error here
    // maybe use a MUI popup modal

    return (
        <Container>
            <Posts posts={posts.posts.posts} />
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Posts.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import Post from "../Post/Post";

import useStyles from "./styles";

function Posts({ posts }) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Grid container className={classes.container} spacing={3} >
            {posts && posts.map((post) => (
                <Grid key={post.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <div className={classes.post}>
                        <Post 
                            id={post.id}
                            title={post.title}
                            content={post.description}
                            creator={post.creator}
                            createdAt={post.createdAt}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default Posts;
```

This is the only place with map() and I've tried adding a key prop to  component as well with no luck. I am extremely confused as I remember there weren't any unique key warning earlier until I started fetching the data dynamically (used temporary post object before).

Comment: console log your post.id in map ..See if there's a key with the same id in the map.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot the ID is referred to as _id.